# I want to call a named template when apply-templates has no match

Tags: xslt

This is a trivial example for a matching problem I'm having in a more complicated XSLT 1.0 stylesheet that generates XSL-FO.

Given this input XML, where `<Library>` may contain zero or more `<Item>` nodes,

```
<Library>
  <Item type="magazine" title="Rum"/>
  <Item type="book" title="Foo" author="Bar"/>
  <Item type="book" title="Fib" author="Fub"/>
  <Item type="magazine" title="Baz"/>
</Library>
```

And this XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="Library">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[@type='Magazine']/>
  <!-- How to call "NoMagazines" from here? -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[@type='Book']/>
  <!-- How to call "NoBooks" from here? -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item[@type='book']">
  <!-- do something with books -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item[@type='magazine']">
  <!-- do something with magazines -->
</xsl:template>

<!-- how to call this template? -->
<xsl:template name="NoBooks">
  Sorry, No Books!
</xsl:template>

<!-- how to call this template? -->
<xsl:template name="NoMagazines">
  Sorry, No Magazines!
</xsl:template>
```

I want to produce the alternative 'Sorry, No [whatever]!' message from the `Library` template when there are no `Item` nodes of the type [whatever].

So far, the only (ugly) solution I've made is to select the child nodes by type into variables, test the variable, then either apply-templates if the variable contains nodes, or call the appropriate 'no match' named template if the variable is empty (I'm assuming test="$foo" will return false if no nodes are selected, I haven't tried it yet):

```
<xsl:template match="Library">
  <xsl:variable name="books" select="Items[@type='book']"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$books">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$books"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="NoBooks"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>

  <xsl:variable name="magazines" select="Items[@type='magazine']"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$magazines">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$magazines"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="NoMagazines"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

I thought this must be an XSLT design pattern (in the GoF sense), but I could find no examples online. Any suggestions are greatly welcomed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this, as a variant of Dimitre's solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my"
>
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <my:errorObjects>
  <noItem type="book">No Books</noItem>
  <noItem type="magazine">No Magazines</noItem>
 </my:errorObjects>

 <xsl:variable name="vErrorObjects" select=
  "document('')/*/my:errorObjects"/>


 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="(.|$vErrorObjects)/*[@type='magazine']/>   
  <xsl:apply-templates select="(.|$vErrorObjects)/*[@type='book']"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Item">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;Type: ', @type, ', title: ', @title)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="noItem">
  <xsl:if test="last() = 1">
    Sorry: <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There is a couple of typographical errors here. Look at the <noItem> starting tag and ending tag. Also missing quote mark on line 18.

Comment: With corrections noted by @SeanB.Durkin this is a little cleaner for my purposes than Dimitre's original solution.

Comment: This solution simplifies the expression in the `select` attribute of `xsl:apply-templates`, however it adds more complexity and dependency into the `errorObjects`. Also, the error template is selected for execution always and the conditional check for `last() = 1` has to be performed every time. It would be nice if the XSLT WG could consider adding a `node-list()` function, so that such templates could be written with all logic in the match pattern and could thus have empty body: `match="noItem[not(node-list()[2])]"` . This resembles the `current-group()` function already existing in XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 3):

The solution below is more concise, but the same principle. It uses the `count()` function to determine if magazine items exist and if not, calls the `NoMagazines` template.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="Library">
        <library>

            <!-- magazines -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[@type='magazine']"/>
            <xsl:if test="count(Item[@type='magazine']) = 0">
                <xsl:call-template name="NoMagazines"/>
            </xsl:if>

            <!-- books -->
            <!-- ... -->

        </library>      
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Item[@type='magazine']">
        <magazine>...</magazine>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="NoMagazines">
        <noMagazines/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

**I would go this way**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my"
>
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <my:errorObjects>
  <noBook>No Books</noBook>
  <noMagazine>No Magazines</noMagazine>
 </my:errorObjects>

 <xsl:variable name="vErrorObjects" select=
  "document('')/*/my:errorObjects"/>


 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
  "*[@type='magazine']
  | $vErrorObjects[not(current()[*[@type='magazine']])]/noMagazine"/>

  <xsl:apply-templates select=
  "*[@type='book']
  | $vErrorObjects[not(current()[*[@type='book']])]/noBook"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Item">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;Type: ', @type, ', title: ', @title)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="my:errorObjects/*">
  Sorry: <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Library>
    <Item type="magazine" title="Rum"/>
    <Item type="book" title="Foo" author="Bar"/>
    <Item type="book" title="Fib" author="Fub"/>
    <Item type="magazine" title="Baz"/>
</Library>
```

**the wanted (normal) results are produced**:

```
Type: magazine, title: Rum
Type: magazine, title: Baz
Type: book, title: Foo
Type: book, title: Fib
```

**When the transformation is applied on the following XML document (no magazines):**

```
<Library>
    <Item type="XXXXX" title="Rum"/>
    <Item type="book" title="Foo" author="Bar"/>
    <Item type="book" title="Fib" author="Fub"/>
    <Item type="YYYYY" title="Baz"/>
</Library>
```

**again the correct result is produced (error message for magazines, normal results for books):**

```
  Sorry: No Magazines
Type: book, title: Foo
Type: book, title: Fib
```

**Similarly, we get the wanted results when there are no books, or when both kind of items are missing**.

**Do note**:

1. **Simplicity** (no modes, no explicit conditional instructions).
2. **Minimum number of templates** (just a single error-processing template, regardless of the number of possible different error types).
3. **Only one `<xsl:apply-templates>` for a given type of processing** -- no need for a special additional `<xsl:apply-templates>` for error processing.
4. **Flexibility, extensibility, maintainability** -- the `errorObjects` can reside in their own, separate file.

Comment: Hi Dimitre, just to confirm my understanding of your solution: `$vErrorObjects[not(current()[*[@type='book']])]/noBook` means "the absence of nodes 'current()', with type='book', taken as 'true' by the effect of 'not()', selects the 'noBook' node from $vErrorObjects, i.e. $vErrorObjects[true()]/noBook". IOW the predicate on $vErrorObjects resolves to 'true' when there are no 'book' nodes?

Comment: BTW, brilliant solution! It surprises me that there is no way to directly test the result of apply-templates - I guess that would be a side effect?

Comment: @psteiner: your understanding of the solution is correct, with the following adjustment: 1. it is not "the absence of nodes 'current()', with type='book'" but "the absence of *child-nodes of* 'current()', with type='book'". 2. The answer to your second question is that to "test the result of applying a template" one needs to capture its output. This is done by applying tempaltes inside the body of a  variable -- then inspecting the value of this variable. In XSLT 2.0 one can have an `xsl:function`. Such function can be referenced inside an XPath expression. Please ask a new question about this

Comment: @psteiner: I am glad that my answer was useful to you. Could you, please *accept* it (by clicking the check-mark next to the answer)?

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I am unfortunately chained to XSLT 1.0 for this project.

Comment: @psteiner: WHere in my solution do you see XSLT 2.0 used? This is a pure XSLT 1.0 solution.

Comment: The solution, yes, but you mentioned "In XSLT 2.0 one can have an xsl:function" in your previous comment.

Comment: psteiner: Yes, but I also mentioned in the same comment how to get the same result in XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use templates that match the "no magazine" and "no books" explicitly:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="Library">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Item" />
  <!-- Apply no[books|magazines] from here -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="noresults" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item[@type='book']">
  <!-- do something with books -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item[@type='magazine']">
  <!-- do something with magazines -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Library[not(Item[@type='book'])]" mode="noresults" >
  Sorry, No Books!
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Library[not(Item[@type='magazine'])]" mode="noresults" >
  Sorry, No Magazines!
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It doesn't work: only one of the Library templates will be invoked. It could perhaps be made to work with some judicious use of xsl:next-match. Downvoting because it is wrong.

Comment: @Michael I's being applied again with a different mode. Can you explain why you think it doesn't work?

Comment: @MichaelKay is right (of course), only one of the "no match" templates will be invoked.

Comment: The approach of this answer can't be salvaged by using xsl:next-match because the OP is using XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't really an original idea. It's just a tweak on Michael's solution. It seems the document() function is a bit problematic for XSLT 1.0, so I've tried to avoid it.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vErrorObjects">
  <Books/><Magazines/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/Library">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[@type='magazine'],$vErrorObjects/Magazines"/>   
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[@type='book'    ],$vErrorObjects/Books"    />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Item">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;Type: ', @type, ', title: ', @title)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Magazines|Books">
  <xsl:if test="last() = 1">
    Sorry: No <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I haven't had problems generally using document() in my XSLT 1.0 stylesheets, can you be more specific?

Comment: I often use online tools to do quick tests of small XSLT 1.0 scripts. The sites I use are www.xmlper.com, http://www.purplegene.com/static/transform.html and http://www.xsltcake.com/ . All these sites crash or don't return when you use the document() function.

Comment: when I run your example in Visual Studio 2008 (MSXML 4?), the expressions `*[@type='magazine'],$vErrorObjects/Magazines` fail with the error `Expected end of the expression, found ','.
*[@type='magazine'] -->,<-- $vErrorObjects/Magazines`. I also tried a join '|', which failed trying to convert the RTF. What was your intent?

Comment: The *[@type='magazine'] is the node set magazine type Items. The comma operator should append this node set with the one <Magazines/> node from the variable.

Comment: According to [Oleg's XSLT version detector](http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000560.html) I am running **Microsoft XslCompiledTransform**, which is provided by the [.Net 4 System.XML.XSL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx) class.

Comment: I'll run this in Saxon to see if I can find out why it isn't working. Saxon has pretty good error reporting.

Comment: I just verified that this works in Saxon. Although Saxon is an XSLT 2.0 processor, the script is marked as 1.0 so it is working in 1.0 backward compatibility mode. So if it works in Saxon in backward compatibility mode, it should work on any fully compliant XSLT 1.0  processor.  May be .Net XSLT has some limitations in respect of XPATH operators?